# Package layout for Go projects using modules to track dependencies?

Tags: go, package

Go now provides [modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) for dependency management, and I'm a little bit confused as to how I should organize my projects.

In traditional `$GOPATH` mode, I would organize an application as follows:

```
├─ cmd/
|  └─ myapp/
|     └─ main.go
├─ otherstuff/
|  └─ file.go
└─ README.md, etc.
```

This is what I see most projects on GitHub doing.

However, now that we have modules, I'm not sure where to put `go.mod`. Does it go in the project's root directory? Does it go in `cmd/[whatever]/`? Should I still be putting `main.go` in the `cmd/[whatever]` directory or should it be in the project's root directory now?

Comment: What is the relationship between cmd/myapp and otherstuff with regard to versioning?  If they are always versioned together, than put go.mod in the root of the repo.  If not, put go.mod in each package.  This will require more effort to maintain.  The path of least resistance is go.mod in root.

Answer (score 2):

[From the wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#modules):

> A module is a collection of related Go packages that are versioned together as a single unit. Most often, a single version-control repository corresponds exactly to a single module, but alternatively, a single version-control repository can hold multiple modules.

So putting `go.mod` right next to `.git` (or equivalent for some other VCS) is almost always the right thing to do. You would only create multiple modules in a single repository if the code in each module is truly independent from the other modules, so that the version of one module does not effect the other modules in any way.